# How to get indent between image and appbar in Flutter app?

Tags: flutter-layout

Here is the code without body of the widget:

```dart
 Column(
    children: [
        Material(
            elevation: 0,
            child: Image.asset(
            i.first,
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
            width: 130,
            child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                child: Text(
                i.last
                ),
            ),
            ),
        ),
    ],
```

Need to add space between appbar and image.

How can i achieve additional space between image and appbar widgets?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Padding` Widget:

```
body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: [
            ...myImageAndCaption.map(
              (i) => Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Material(
                    elevation: 0,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      i.first,
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      height: 150,
                      width: 150,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 130,
                    child: FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                        child: Text(
                          i.last,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 22,
                            letterSpacing: 1.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: when i using above code getting bottom overflowed by 5 pixels

Comment: use padding: const EdgeInsets.only( top: 8.0),

Comment: with this code + also wrap the top padding widget with SingleChildScrollView